# Resize elements to fit container

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `ul` which inside has some `li` elements.
How do i prevent the elements inside from breaking their line, without overflowing their container.

I think i need to adjust the `font-size` and `margin` on the `li` elements.
But how, i do not know.
Any ideas what the approach to the problem is ?

Keep in mind this is a menu.

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/gken6/

Comment: Why can't you just make it fit? Is that menu dynamically generated?

Comment: It is dynamically generated.

Comment: And how would you like to handle long item names? Change the font size dynamically?

Comment: A combination between margin and font size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I understand correctly your question and if this will help
But with this code if you increases the number of elements in the list the font size is decreased to fit the container.
Of course this code should be improved but it was just to give you an idea
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/videma/aUKJZ/)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    function decrease () {
        var count=0
        function recursor(count){
                var containerW=$('.container').width()
                var liW=$('.container li').width()
                console.log(liW)
                var nuberLinks=$('.container li').length
                var total=liW*nuberLinks
                if(total>=containerW){
                   $('.container ul').css({'font-size':20-count+'px'})
                    count++
                    recursor(count)
                }
        };
        recursor(0);
    };
    decrease();
})
</script>
```

If this solution does not suit your needs, i apologize for making you lose time.

Comment: This is for sure something i can work with. Thank you.